# Is it better to use path() or url() in urls.py for django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In a django online course, the instructor has us use the `url()` function to call views and utilize regular expressions in the urlpatterns list. I've seen other examples on youtube of this.
e.g.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]


#and in polls/urls.py

urlpatterns = [        
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

However, in going through the Django tutorial, they use `path()` instead e.g.:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),        
]
```

Furthermore regular expressions don't seem to work with the `path()` function as using a `path(r'^$', views.index, name="index")` won't find the `mysite.com/polls/` view.

Is using `path()` without regex matching the proper way going forward? Is `url()` more powerful but more complicated so they're using `path()` to start us out with? Or is it a case of different tools for different jobs?

Comment: If you are following a tutorial, I would use whichever style the tutorial uses, to prevent mistakes when switching between `path()` and `url()`. If you want or need to use regexes, then you must use `re_path()` or `url()`. Beyond that, I think it's really up to you which one you choose.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

From Django documentation for [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url)

> `url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None)` This function
> is an alias to `django.urls.re_path()`. It’s likely to be deprecated in
> a future release.

Key difference between [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) and [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path) is that `path` uses route without regex

You can use `re_path` for complex regex calls and use just `path` for simpler lookups

Answer (score 95):

The new [`django.urls.path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) function allows a simpler, more readable URL routing syntax. For example, this example from previous Django releases:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive)
```

could be written as:

```
path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive)
```

The **`django.conf.urls.url()`**  function from previous versions is now available as [**`django.urls.re_path()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path). The old location remains for backwards compatibility, without an imminent deprecation. The old **`django.conf.urls.include()`** function is now importable from **`django.urls`** so you can use:

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
```

in the **URLconfs**. For further reading [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax)

Comment: A little misleading since your `path()` example allows non-four-digit numbers.

Comment: The `/<int:year>/` signifies that the year should be in integer, i suggest you look through the official documentation.

Comment: @silvablaze As BrainCore stated, `int` is not equivalent to `[0-9]{4}`. Whether it is used for integers or not has no bearing on this relationship. Perhaps if you replaced `[0-9]{4}` with `[0-9]+` your comparison might be less inaccurate, although you might still need to deal with the type of the end result (str vs int?).

Answer (score 21):

`path` is simply new in Django 2.0, which was only released a couple of weeks ago. Most tutorials won't have been updated for the new syntax.

It was certainly supposed to be a simpler way of doing things; I wouldn't say that URL is more powerful though, you should be able to express patterns in either format.

Answer (score 10):

Regular expressions don't seem to work with the `path()` function with the following arguments: `path(r'^$', views.index, name="index")`.

It should be like this: `path('', views.index, name="index")`.

The 1st argument must be blank to enter a regular expression.

Comment: Yes, I think as pointed out above to use REs you have to use the re_path() function instead.

Answer (score 9):

Path is a new feature of Django 2.0.
Explained here :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#whats-new-2-0

Look like more pythonic way, and enable to not use regular expression in argument you pass to view... you can ue int() function for exemple.

Answer (score 5):

From v2.0 many users are using path, but we can use either path or url.
For example in django 2.1.1
mapping to functions through url can be done as follows

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from django.contrib.auth import login
from posts.views import post_home
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/$', post_home, name='post_home'),

]
```

where posts is an application & post_home is a function in views.py