# Django 2.0 Trying to Grab the primary key with regular Expressions but im getting 404

Tags: python, django

This is my Code ..

```
urlpatterns =[
path('',views.School_Lview.as_view(),name='list'),
path('(?P<pk>\d+)/',views.School_Dview.as_view(),name='detail')
]
```

I am trying to get this template to work

```
{% for school in schools %}
<h2><li><a href="{{school.id}}"> {{school.name}}</a></li></h2>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: I am trying to link a particular school (among other schools) detailview..

Comment: try this in url,   your_app_name/'(?P<pk>\d+)/

Comment: It says app not defined..and i am using django2.0 so url() doesnt work so im using path ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947673/is-it-better-to-use-path-or-url-in-urls-py-for-django-2-0

Comment: it should work, you are doing any mistake, do you have registered your app in settings.py????

Comment: Thanks For The Help @Sagar

Comment: @Sagar Please post this as an answer so it can be accepted and the question closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Fixed it...I used re_path instead of path and it worked like a charm..

```
re_path('(?P<pk>\d+)/',views.School_Dview.as_view(),name='detail')
```

Answer (score 2):

django2.0 don't support the use of regex in **[django.urls.path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path)** else if you really want to write the regex in your urls i will advice you use 
**[django.urls.re_path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path)** which is the new function for the old version **django.conf.urls.url**

difference between **path()** and **re_path()**

with **path()** your urls would be written as;

```
from urls import path
urlpatterns =[
   path('',views.School_Lview.as_view(),name='list'),
   path('<int:pk>/',views.School_Dview.as_view(),name='detail')
]
```

with **re_path()**

```
from urls import path
 urlpatterns =[
    re_path('',views.School_Lview.as_view(),name='list'),
    re_path('(?P<pk>\d+)/',views.School_Dview.as_view(),name='detail')
 ]
```

check the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) for more insight on urls routing in django2.0

Answer (score 1):

While the answers are correct I just wanted to point out that `Django` actually uses the regular expression `[0-9]+` instead of `\d+` for primary keys.

They both have the same effect but [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0367bc6d04ca6d1a4a21a69a839f6d404508f8df/django/urls/converters.py#L5) you can see all the default converters and their regular expressions who are hidden behind the 'new' path syntax.