# Django URL pattern doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have my `urls.py` included like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('files/', include('files.urls')),
]
```

then, in `files/urls.py`, I put this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path(r'(?P<name>[a-z]+)', views.check, name='check')
]
```

So, I assume that when `example.com/files` works, so should `example.com/files/somename`, but it doesn't:

> Using the URLconf defined in example.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> [name='index']
> files/ [name='index']
> files/ (?P<name>[a-z]+) [name='check']
> ```
>
> The current path, files/somename, didn't match any of these.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947947/5312750) will help.

Comment: You mix `url(..)`s and `path(..)`s: Django has several ways to specify URLs, each with their own notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use regexp with `path` method. Instead you can simply specify `str` as argument  type:

```
path('<str:name>/', views.check, name='check')
```

If you want to use regular expression, use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path):

```
re_path(r'(?P<name>[a-z]+)', views.check, name='check')
```