# How to create delete button for deleting a record in django

Tags: django

I am trying to delete a record
My views.py file is

```
def AnnouncementDelete(request, pk):
    announcement = get_object_or_404(Announcement, pk=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        announcement.delete()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'classroom/announcement_confirm_delete.html')
```

and my html file is

```
{% extends "classroom/base.html" %} 
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'classroom:AnnouncementDelete' announcement.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Delete cat">
    </form>
{% endblock content%}
```

my url.py file has the pattern

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AnnouncementDelete, name='AnnouncementDelete'),
```

and the model from where I want to delete the record is

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

when I am trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/classroom/delete/1/

it is giving me the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /classroom/delete/1/
Reverse for 'AnnouncementDelete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classroom/delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Also i am a beginner to django and not very familiar with `url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AnnouncementDelete, name='AnnouncementDelete'),` way. I generally use the ```path`` way.

***EDIT***
This is the view for uploading assignment

```
 @login_required
def upload_announcement(request):
    if(request.user.is_teacher==False):
        return HttpResponse("This forms requires teacher previlodge")
    else:    
        assignment_uploaded = False
        teacher = request.user.Teacher
        if request.method== 'POST':
            form = AnnouncementForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                upload = form.save(commit=False)
                upload.teacher = teacher
                upload.save()
                assignment_uploaded = True
        else:
            form = AnnouncementForm()
        return render(request, 'classroom/announcement_form.html', {'form':form, 'assignment_uploaded':assignment_uploaded})
```

This is the view for displaying all assignments

```
class AnnouncementListView(ListView):
    context = {
            'announcements' : Announcement.objects.all()
        }
    model  =  Announcement
    template_name = 'classroom/all_announcements.html' #<app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'announcements'
```

Comment: show your `view` that renders the `announcement` html

Comment: Try `path('delete/<int:pk>', ...` in your urls.py.

Comment: ```path('delete/<int:pk>', ...``` returned a page not found error

Comment: @SLDem edited in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can discard the url() line and use the path() variant for this like that:

```py
path("delete/<int:pk>/", view=views.AnnouncementDelete, name="AnnouncementDelete"),
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, please report back with the view that renders the delete page.

Comment: My page not error was because there was no forward slash after ```delete/<int:pk>``` worked with ```path("delete/<int:pk>/", view=views.AnnouncementDelete, name="AnnouncementDelete"),```

Answer (score 0):

In your html template you are using a variable (`announcement`) that you never pass from your view.

If i am thinking of this right, you should change your view to:

```
def AnnouncementDelete(request, pk):
    announcement = get_object_or_404(Announcement, pk=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        announcement.delete()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'classroom/announcement_confirm_delete.html', {'announcement': announcement}) 
# this last guy over here sends the desired object to the template for rendering.
```

#### You did't ask for this but...

Since you mention in your question that you use `path` most of the times, i assume that you just wanted to test `url`.
Regarding the proper use of `url` variant check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947947/10269515).

Comment: Alog with page not found error i got ```The current path, classroom/delete/1/, didn't match any of these.```

Comment: Did you include your app urls to the project's urls?
i.e.
`# project urls
urlpatterns = [
path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]`

Comment: yes i did. I have also created various urls before in this project